# Vector of class object

Tags: c++, class, oop, constructor, stdvector

I was wondering how to create a vector of class object with custom constructors, though I ran into a problem with std::vector.push_back(), how am i supposed to create a new element in the vector with its constructor?

CODE:

```
class sampleClass{
    private:
        std::string cID;
        int cNum;
    public:
        sampleClass(std::string inputID, int inputNum){
            cID = inputID;
            cNum = inputNum;
        }
}

int main(){
    std::vector<sampleClass> vSC;
    
    vSC.push_back("id1", 1);
    vSC.push_back("id2", 2);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's what emplace_back can do

Comment: `push_back` wants an object that it can copy, `emplace_back` creates a new object from constructor arguments.

Comment: @molbdnilo to nitpick a bit push_back can also move ;)

Comment: Don't do `sampleClass(std::string inputID, int inputNum){
            cID = inputID;
            cNum = inputNum;
        }` instead do `sampleClass(std::string inputID, int inputNum) : cID{inputID}, cNum{inputNum} { }` .

Comment: If you can't/won't use `emplace_back()` for some reason, you can construct the object in the `push_back()` call e.g. `vSC.push_back(sampleClass("id1", 1))`.   Before C++11, a copy of the temporarily constructed object is appended (no guarantee of elision).   From C++11, the temporary is moved.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with [`emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back):

```cpp
vSC.emplace_back("id1", 1);
vSC.emplace_back("id2", 2);
```

> ```
> template< class... Args >
> constexpr reference emplace_back( Args&&... args );
> ```
>
> Appends a new element to the end of the container. The element is constructed through `std::allocator_traits::construct`, which typically uses placement-`new` to construct the element in-place at the location provided by the container. The arguments `args...` are forwarded to the constructor as `std::forward<Args>(args)...`.

Comment: You *could* also `.push_back({"id1", 1});`, but that would of course involve an extra copy that `emplace_back` avoids.

Comment: @JesperJuhl True indeed!

Answer (score 1):

You can use emplace_back, also do not initialize your members in the body of your constructor but use the proper initialization syntax :

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class sampleClass
{
public:
    sampleClass(const std::string& inputID, int inputNum) :
        cID{ inputID },
        cNum{ inputNum }
    {
        // do not initialize members in the body of your constructor
    }

    const std::string& ID() const noexcept
    {
        return cID;
    }

    int Num() const noexcept
    {
        return cNum;
    }

private:
    std::string cID;
    int cNum;

};

int main() 
{
    std::vector<sampleClass> vSC;

    vSC.emplace_back("id1", 1);
    vSC.emplace_back("id2", 2);

    // range based for loop
    for (const auto& sample : vSC)
    {
        std::cout << sample.Num() << ", " << sample.ID() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```